# Create mixed (value set) CPPDEFINES in SCons

Tags: python, scons

I'd like to set the compiler defines to **-DBLUB** as well as **-DFOO=1**.

Currently I only have:

```
env.Append("CPPDEFINES", ["BLUB", "VALUE2"])
```

I now would like to include a third define via *"FOO" : 1* and thus use *CPPDEFINES* as a dictionary so I can later on test quite easy

```
env["CPPDEFINES"].get("FOO") == 1
```

or so. Everything I attempted leads to syntax errors or strange errors.
Could one explain the strange ways to do this in python to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to specify a value for any single define, `CPPDEFINES` must be a dictionary.

From the [scons User Manual](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.0.1/HTML/scons-user.html#app-variables):

> If $CPPDEFINES is a dictionary, the values of the $CPPDEFPREFIX and $CPPDEFSUFFIX construction variables will be appended to the beginning and end of each item from the dictionary. The key of each dictionary item is a name being defined to the dictionary item's corresponding value; if the value is None, then the name is defined without an explicit value.

For your example, I suggest:

```
env.Append(CPPDEFINES = { 'BLUB': None, 'VALUE2': None, 'Foo': 1 })
```

or

```
env.Append(CPPDEFINES = { 'BLUB': None, 'VALUE2': None })
...and sometime later...
env.Append(CPPDEFINES = { 'Foo': 1 })
```

Comment: You __CANNOT__ use *env.Append* on a new Environment since *CPPDEFINES* is initialized as a list and Append just adds the Dictionary as a list item. For this to work you have to use *env["CPPDEFINES"] = { 'Foo' : 1}* so that the actual *CPPDEFINES* type/variable is replaced.

Comment: @LCIDFire `CPPDEFINES` is not initialized as a list for me in a new Environment in scons 2.0.1. When I create a new Environment, I can use the code I wrote above. You're right to point out that if `CPPDEFINES` is already a list, you'll get errors - thus the first line of my answer :)

Comment: For the list, you can handle it with: `env.Append(CPPDEFINES = ['BLUB', 'VALUE2', ('Foo', '1')])`. It will result on `-DBLUB -DVALUE2 -DFoo=1` You should add it in your answer.

Comment: @Phong, How to pass a string value? say `-DFoo="Bla-Bla"`. Adding ('Foo', "Bla-Bla") ending up like `#define Foo Bla-Bla`, while I want to get `#define Foo "Bla-Bla". Thanks.

Comment: Answering my own question. Defining strings needs a lot escapes: `env.Append(CPPDEFINES = [('Foo' , '\\"Bla-Bla\\"')])`